# Redis cache item invalidation by extra tags

Tags: caching, redis

I'm planning to use Redis for caching. Beside basic caching, there is a special requirement: solution must be capable of invalidating cached items by "extra keys"; these are collection of business entity types with id, practically KVPs. Example: `client:12345` or `account:4567`. There can be multiple KVPs associated to a cache item and cache invalidation can be invoked with only providing a KVP collection. Only those items are subjects for invalidation that match all given extra key criteria (in one step).

I'm thinking of combining standard cache with sets, like the following:

1. Storing items: `SET key1 value1`, `SET key2 value2`
2. Storing extra keys:`SADD client:1234 key1 key2`, `SADD account:4567 key2`, `SADD card:987 key2`
3. Invalidation by extra key: delete all keys given by `SMEMBERS account:4567` then `DEL account:4567`
4. Invalidation by extra keys: delete all keys given by `SINTER account:4567 client:1234`, then `SREM` them from account:4567 and client:1234

Is it good enough (in terms of performance and stability), or there is a better way to do this?